# How can I make text appear on another page in a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, button, input

I am making a get started button on my website, where the person enters his email and then presses "get started". The text should then be transferred to my login page in the email field.

Here is my code for the button:

```
                    <form method="post" action="#" class="container 50%">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="8u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" /></div>
                            <div class="4u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="button" value="Get Started" class="fit special" onclick="location.href='loginsystem/loginpage.php';"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And here is my code for the login page:

```
<?php
/* Main page with two forms: sign up and log in */
require 'db.php';
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
<?php include 'css/css.html'; ?>
</head>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in

    require 'login.php';

}

elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering

    require 'register.php';

}
}
?>
<body style="background-color: #1c1d26">
<div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

     <div id="login">
      <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

      <form action="loginpage.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" required autocomplete="off" name="email"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" required autocomplete="off" name="password"/>
      </div>

      <p class="forgot"><a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password?</a></p>

      <button class="button button-block" name="login" />Log In</button>

      </form>

    </div>

    <div id="signup">
      <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

      <form action="loginpage.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            First Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name='firstname' />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name='lastname' />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
        Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off" name='email' />
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
        Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" name='password'/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="register" />Register</button>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div><!-- tab-content -->

  </div> <!-- /form -->
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'>            </script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: u could, instead of doing location change inside onclick, simply make it a [submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) with type="submit" and e.g. name="submit" + add an [action attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) to your form pointing to your php file - in ur php u can then ask for $_POST['submit'] and get the input data from $_POST['email'] - btw. you should maybe investigate a bit time into html form's and when/why to use js & php or even better what is their use case ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your get started `form` set `action="yourLoginPage.php"`

```
<form method="post" action="yourLoginPage.php" class="container 50%">
```

In your login page

```
<input type="email" required autocomplete="off" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>"/>
```